# React cannot display notification of a 401 response.statusText for unauthorized login, also this is undefined warning?

Tags: reactjs, fetch, http-status-code-401

I am trying to intentionally display a notification showing that the user credentials are incorrect or unauthorized. Yet nothing displays

The following is the React component:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import ReactDom from "react-dom";
import '../css/app.scss';
import 'bootstrap';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';

export class Login extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state={
            email:'',
            password:'',
            username:'',
            errorMsg:'',
            hasError: false
        }
    }

    handleClick() {
        fetch('/login', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'credentials': "same-origin"
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                'email' : this.state.email,
                'password' : this.state.password,
                'username' : this.state.username
            })
        })
        .then(function(response) {
            if (!response.ok) {
                if (response.status === 401) {
                    console.log(response.statusText);
                    this.setState({'hasError': true});
                    this.setState({'errorMsg': response.statusText})
                }
            }
        })
        .catch(error => console.log(error) );
    }

    render() {
        const hasError = this.state.hasError;
        let hasErrorDiv;

        if (hasError) {
            hasErrorDiv = <div id="mAlert" className="alert alert-danger">{this.state.errorMsg}</div>;
        } else {
            hasErrorDiv = <div id="mAlert" ></div>;
        };
        return (
            <div className="container">
                <div>
                    {hasErrorDiv}
                    <TextField
                        type="text"
                        hinttext="Enter your username"
                        floatinglabeltext="username"
                        onChange = {(event) => this.setState({username:event.currentTarget.value})}
                    />
                    <br/>
                    <TextField
                        type="email"
                        hinttext="Enter your email"
                        floatinglabeltext="email"
                        onChange = {(event) => this.setState({email:event.currentTarget.value})}
                    />
                    <br/>
                    <TextField
                        type="password"
                        hinttext="Enter your Password"
                        floatinglabeltext="Password"
                        onChange = {(event) => this.setState({password:event.currentTarget.value})}
                    />
                    <br/>
                    <Button label="Login" onClick={() => this.handleClick()}>
                        Login
                    </Button>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

ReactDom.render(<Login />, document.getElementById('Login'));
```

As you can see with the following screen shot:

[image: the server returns invalid credentials]

I would like to display the error to the end user

Also, in the console is something strange, because I thought that a 401 response is not considered to be an error, so what is the catch error, which is displaying in the console, referring to?

Thanks in advance

Comment: 401 is an error.

Comment: Thanks for responding @trognanders, but 401 is an unauthorized error not a response error, which means that it passes the catch error

Comment: Oh word. You need to bind this to functions passed from class react components to dom handlers.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I had to create my own notification process for handling 401 errors.

First, not all notifications work with React 16.13.2

Second, the error message of "this is undefined" came from within the catch not understanding what "this" was sepecifically.

Third, I had to use the async type, followed by using the await - for waiting for the response to be returned from the fetch POST.

Fourth, I had to use .json to be able to read the error, which was in JSON - {'error':'Invalid credentials'} - see screen shot below

The following is my code:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import ReactDom from "react-dom";
import '../css/app.scss';
import 'bootstrap';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import $ from 'jquery';

export class Login extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state={
            email:'',
            password:'',
            username:'',
            errorMsg:'',
            hasError: false
        };
        this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        // console.log(React.version);
    }

    setNotifications(param) {
        // console.log('makes it to setNotification func');
        let notifications = $('#notificaitons');
        notifications.addClass("alert alert-danger");
        notifications.html(param.error);
    }

    async handleClick() {
        const requestOptions = {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'credentials': "same-origin"
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                'email' : this.state.email,
                'password' : this.state.password,
                'username' : this.state.username
            })
        };
        const response = await fetch('/login', requestOptions);
        const data = await response.json();
        this.setState({ errorMsg: data.error });
        this.setNotifications(data);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="container">
                <div>
                    <div id="notificaitons"></div>
                    <TextField
                        type="text"
                        hinttext="Enter your username"
                        floatinglabeltext="username"
                        onChange = {(event) => this.setState({username:event.currentTarget.value})}
                    />
                    <br/>
                    <TextField
                        type="email"
                        hinttext="Enter your email"
                        floatinglabeltext="email"
                        onChange = {(event) => this.setState({email:event.currentTarget.value})}
                    />
                    <br/>
                    <TextField
                        type="password"
                        hinttext="Enter your Password"
                        floatinglabeltext="Password"
                        onChange = {(event) => this.setState({password:event.currentTarget.value})}
                    />
                    <br/>
                    <Button label="Login" onClick={() => this.handleClick()}>
                        Login
                    </Button>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

ReactDom.render(<Login />, document.getElementById('Login'));
```

[image: screen shot of the fetch 401 response]

Now granted, I have to do a lot more coding, like how to clear the notificaiton, probably some kind of fade, and probably have to do some kind of success notification, along with a warning version but at least it works.

BTW, it's just a div that I add a class of 'alert alert-danger', along with adding the contents via .html. To make a success version, I will add a class of 'alert alert-success' and so on

Comment: It looks like you started using jquery to get a `ref` to one of the rendered components which is definitely not idiomatic react. Strongly suggest refactoring so that `notifications` is re-rendered with data from `state` instead of covertly modified through DOM.